# Are snow spikes for boots allowed in hand luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, hand-luggage

Are snow spikes (like [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K1I3BLU)) allowed in hand luggage when flying?

Comment: Which country/airport?

Comment: All over western and eastern Europe.

Comment: I'd put them in my checked luggage.

Comment: I would argue that those are closer to chains than spikes, but it's coming down to the discretion of the individual screener if they look in your bag. You could consider a traction device more like [these](https://www.yaktrax.com/product/walk), which are less spiky, but they may be less effective for their intended purpose.

Comment: Is there any reason you need them in your hand luggage?  Or why you might need them before you get your checked luggage ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Blades and scissors under 6cm are typically allowed. For example [Heathrow](http://www.heathrow-airport-guide.co.uk/security.html), [Zurich](https://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/arrivals-and-departures/security-checks). So if your spikes are less than 6cm, you are certainly good to go.
2. There are [winter studs](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ultrasport-Outdoor-Spikes-Shoe-Black/dp/B00AFAMQ02) instead of the spikes.

Answer (score 5):

I brought microspikes (virtually the same as these spikes) in my hand luggage twice in late May this year, on Ryanair STN-BCN and Vueling BCN-LGW flights, for hiking in the Pyrenees. There was no problem each time.

Comment: I have the same experience. Never had problems but that doesn't guarantee that there will never be.

Answer (score 4):

I know OP clarified in a comment that they were asking about Europe, but since the question wasn't tagged "europe" and another answer relating to the TSA received upvotes, I thought I would post my own findings relating to the TSA's stance on snow spikes (a.k.a. crampons).

There is conflicting information on the TSA's web site as to whether crampons are allowed in carry-on bags.  [One of their blog posts](http://blog.tsa.gov/2014/05/tsa-travel-tips-travel-tips-for.html) from 2014 says "Crampons are permitted in both carry-on and checked baggage".

However, their undated [What Can I Bring](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/printable) page says "No" to carry-on bags and "Yes" to checked bags.

The [AskTSA twitter feed](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=asktsa%20crampons&src=typd&lang=en) seems to clear up the issue, as most of their responses to users since late 2016 have said that "Crampons and micro spikes are allowed in checked bags only".

There does appear to be one exception though.  A user asked about [Yaktrax style crampons](https://twitter.com/xminustDC/status/846034538212085761), and the TSA said "crampons without spikes are allowed in carry-on bags".

Answer (score 3):

You will never get a sufficient answer, because the item is too special. 
The TSA does not have it in their Item-List of [Prohibited Items](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/prohibited-items), so you are relying on the personal opinion of the person at the security check. 
Either you ask TSA via Email and print the mail and hope the best (if they allow it in the Email), or just put them in your checked luggage to avoid confusion, stress and additional time for discussions

Comment: Europe does not have TSA, but the rules are often the same.

Comment: Not just Europe: everywhere except the US does not have the TSA. Please don't assume that everybody is in the USA, especially when the comments to the question explicitly say that it's about Europe.

Comment: All of western and eastern Europe can be literally everywhere in Europe, inside and outside of the EU. Consequently, there might be several different restrictions on flight luggage. I used the TSA as example, because they are among the biggest, well known and quite strict organisations regarding luggage-"security" questions. As the OP did not specify which countries are concerned, reason based on the TSA rules are a good try.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this answer and subsequently got distracted and didn't undo my downvote. If the answer's edited, please @mention me in a comment and I'll undo the downvote.